# Array of values in List view

Tags: admin-on-rest

What is the proper way to achieve the visual equivalent of this:

[image: ReferenceManyField]

, but for an array that is part of the entity of the `Resource` itself (as opposed being a field on a referenced entity)? For instance, if my document looked like `{"id": 1, "title": "my title", "comments_by": ["john", "kate"]}`.

I tried to nest a `List` element but wasn't able to make it look right.

Comment: I found a temporary workaround, which is to use a `FunctionField` and join the values, but it doesn't look very nice (especially if my values already contain the join separator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track; This should achieve your goal:

```
<FunctionField render={record=>
  record.comments_by.map((by,index)=> <ChipField record={{by}} source="by"/>)
}/>
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! Intuitively I was looking for an `ArrayField`, or maybe a `SelectArrayField` (to match `SelectArrayInput`). Hopefully searching for it will lead people here!